# Django model form.save() not saving

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm trying to create a page where I can edit my articles as an authenticated user, however when form.save() is called nothing is being saved.

here is the codes

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def edit(request, id=None, template_name='article_edit.html'):
    if id:
        article = get_object_or_404(Article, pk=id)
        if article.user != request.user:
            return HttpResponseForbidden()
    else:
        article = Article(user=request.user)

    if request.POST:
        form = ArticleForm(request.POST, instance=article)
        if form.is_valid():
            save_it = form.save(commit=False)
            save_it.save()
            form.save_m2m()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/")

    else:
        form = ArticleForm(instance=article)

    context = {'form': form}
    populateContext(request, context)
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

**models.py**

```
class Article(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    titre = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    summary = RichTextField(null=True, max_length=140)
    contenu = RichTextField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.titre
```

**forms.py**

```
class ArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        exclude = ['user']

form = ArticleForm()
```

What is wrong and why the form.save() is not saving? Any help would be helpfull.

Comment: any errors that you can see when you post the form?

Comment: What does it do instead of saving? Does it just redirect without doing anything?

Comment: You should be saving the *Model* not the *Form*.  This is a common mistake with Django Forms.

Comment: Does the model instance resulting from `form.save(commit=False)` have `user` field set? I guess there might be issues arising from the fact it's excluded from the form.

Answer (score 0):

Try  form.save(commit= True), might work

Answer (score -2):

You should be saving the `Model` not the `Form`. This is a common mistake with Django Forms

Comment: It is a model form so it is perfectly valid to save a form object.